# jQuery FadeOut FadeIn Running Multiple Times

Tags: jquery

What have I got wrong here? Basically I have three radio buttons, and when I click one I want to make all matching Divs fade Out, and then Fade the One matching Div back in.

What actually happens is when I click the radio Button all my Divs fade Out as expected, but then the new one Fades In, then Out, then back In again.

```
changePage = function()
{
    $('.pageAlt').on('click',function() //click a radio button with class pageAlt
        {
            pageVal=$(this).val(); // get the Value for this button (1,2,3,4)

            $('.divScriptsTableOuter').fadeOut('slow',function() // FadeOut all Divs (as they all have class divScriptsTableOuter)
                {
                    switch (pageVal) // FadeIn the One Div that matches
                        {
                            case "1":
                                $('#divONE').delay(500).fadeIn();
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                $('#divTWO').delay(500).fadeIn();
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                $('#divTHREE').delay(500).fadeIn();
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                $('#divFOUR').delay(500).fadeIn();
                                break;
                            default:
                                $('#divONE').delay(500).fadeIn();
                        }
                })
        })
}
```

Comment: Could you add your html?

Comment: Paste your htlm as well .or Jsfilldle please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it an another way... Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pageAlt').on('click', function() {
    var $el = null;
    pageVal = $(this).val();
    switch (pageVal)
    {
      case "1":
        $el = $('#divONE');
        break;
      case "2":
        $el = $('#divTWO');
        break;
      case "3":
        $el = $('#divTHREE');
        break;
      case "4":
        $el = $('#divFOUR');
        break;
      default:
        $el = $('#divFIVE');
    }      
    $('.divScriptsTableOuter').not($el.fadeOut("slow").delay(500).fadeIn()).fadeOut('slow');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pageAlt" type="radio" name="val" value="1"> 1
<br>
<input class="pageAlt" type="radio" name="val" value="2"> 2
<br>
<input class="pageAlt" type="radio" name="val" value="3"> 3
<br>
<input class="pageAlt" type="radio" name="val" value="4"> 4
<br>
<input class="pageAlt" type="radio" name="val" value="5"> 5
<div id="divONE" class="divScriptsTableOuter">
  1
</div>
<div id="divTWO" class="divScriptsTableOuter">
  2
</div>
<div id="divTHREE" class="divScriptsTableOuter">
  3
</div>
<div id="divFOUR" class="divScriptsTableOuter">
  4
</div>
<div id="divFIVE" class="divScriptsTableOuter">
  5
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, I was actually looking at something similar but couldn't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is related to the `fadeOut` callback which is:

> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Note the "once per matched element", so your callback is called for every matched element once it fades out.

I've reproduced your issue in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/kpk155Le/). To fix it, you'll have to wait until every element has fade out before you `fadeIn` the one you want.

Here's my solution:

1. `fadeOut` everything when dom loads
2. `fadeOut` only the hidden elements, without waiting for it to finish
3. `fadeIn` the selected one

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/kpk155Le/1/).

Comment: Cheers, that explains what I was seeing.